# How do I compile grails project using grails command line?

Tags: grails

How do I compile my grails project? I want to get a `.war` file so I can deploy it.

First I installed JDK then I installed grails and I have properly set environment variables for both and checked it.Now I want to compile this grails project using grails command line.how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which grails version?

Answer (score 0):

If you type "grails help", you'll get a list of all the grails commands. The one you're looking for is "grails war"

Comment: But first I want to import my grails project .After Importing I want to compile it to get its .war file